# UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent: iOS7 no user code

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit, ios7

I have a crash that is occurring on iOS7 only. The app is compiled against 6.1 sdk. I can not reproduce this myself but I can see from crash reports that it is occurring for some users. The problem is there is no user code in the stack trace so it is proving difficult to track down:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x13
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 5
1    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
2    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
3    UIKit   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
4    UIKit   -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
5    UIKit   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
6    UIKit   -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
7    UIKit   -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
8    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
9    UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7096
10 ...   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
16   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

I have tried enabling zombies and performing various actions in the app but that didn't flag anything.

### Update

I think this might have morphed in to [UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows], EXC_BAD_ACCESS under iOS 7.1 . I will investigate further.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39576626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x3187b12f -[UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows] + 54
2  UIKit                          0x3187b26f -[UIPickerView didMoveToWindow] + 78
3  UIKit                          0x3160ad37 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1358
4  UIKit                          0x3160aaa5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 700
5  UIKit                          0x3160a40d __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 112
6  UIKit                          0x3160a263 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 250
7  UIKit                          0x318a2a27 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 218
8  UIKit                          0x31609187 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 270
9  UIKit                          0x316cf26f -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) adjustHostViewForTransitionCompletion:] + 310
10 UIKit                          0x31a6ca8b __53-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]_block_invoke1364 + 318
11 UIKit                          0x3164378d -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 284
12 UIKit                          0x316433d7 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 178
13 UIKit                          0x316432ef -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
14 QuartzCore                     0x3128de0b CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 234
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x39a55d3f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x39a586c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2eda6679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2eda4f45 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2ed0f7a9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2ed0f58b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21 GraphicsServices               0x33c6c6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
22 UIKit                          0x3166e891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Comment: During testing have you tapped everything which is tappable (and checked in code that all action methods actually exist)?

Comment: Yup, I hit all the buttons on the view controller where I suspect it is happening. I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Note that it only occurs on iOS7 devices.

Comment: I haven't found the cause yet.

Comment: Does the pickerview data change for some reason after viewDidLoad()?

Comment: no the data is static

Comment: I think this crash log is related to a UIPickerView when it hasn't been started properly. Is it the number of elements in your array for the rows the same number of the indicated number of rows in the delegate method "numberOfRowsInComponent:"?  Are you retaining a reference to the picker? It could be that it's being auto released before time. why don't you paste the code so we can help better

Comment: In our case, it was caused by a UIPickerView being used as a custom inputView (i.e. replacement for keyboard) that was left up and open when the ViewController was changed out for another. The hide animation from the automatic resignFirstResponder triggered the crash.

Comment: @maple yes thats what I have narrowed it down to as well. How did you fix it?

Comment: @Imran I added `[self.nameOfYourPickerViewObject removeFromSuperview]` to the dealloc method of the pickerView's delegate. (As per the comments in BandoKal's answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I had the almost identical crash log with our project we were able to track to an animation. 
The problem was that we animated a UIPickerView on and off the screen. If the ViewController that owned the UIPickerView was popped and dealloced during the animation. We solved this by removing the UIPickerView from the superview in the animation completion block.

`[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
          //Set the destination frame of the PickerView
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];
     }];`

Comment: Similarly, the built-in animation on resignFirstResponder (during a ViewController change) caused it for me. `removeFromSuperview` in dealloc did the trick.

Comment: I think you might be on to something, looks like I can reproduce it but in a slightly different way, if I flick the picker wheel so it is still animating whilst I pop the view controller, I get this crash. I will investigate a fix.

Comment: If I compile it against iOS7 it is no longer reproducable. Maybe the problem only exists when running apps compiled against iOS6 on iOS7. Will do more testing.

Comment: @Imran have you been able to confirm that the problem only exist with apps compiled against 6 running on 7?

Comment: @zrxq I havent confirmed it yet for sure but I think this is the case. Once I release an update compiled against iOS7 I will have more stats and will update this post with my findings.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can reproduce the issue on iOS7 (in an app, linked against iOS7). Let me know if you're interested in a showcase project reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other crash reporting tools, but Crashlytics includes the CLS_LOG() macro:
http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92519-how-do-i-use-logging

During development, it behaves as NSLog() but in the field, the log statements are included in crash reports. So I suggest replacing your debugging statements with CLS_LOG or start peppering the code in question with lots of statements that capture the user actions, then deploy a new version of your app.

(Old question, but I recently ran into something similar and would like to document this.)

Comment: Thanks Bart, I am using crashlytics and have breadcrumbs so I know which screen it is occurring on. Tracking it down to a specific user action on that screen is proving difficult though.

Answer (score 0):

All I just received a similar crash with a UIPicker. Turns out that I forgot to set the delegate to nil before deallocating it. The problem only presented when running with breakpoints enabled. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score -3):

Try removing `arm64` from:

`Project > BuildSettings > Architectures> Valid Architectures`

and rebuilding you app.

You might also need to set `Build Active Architectures Only` to `NO` for it to work.

Comment: This happens on 4s, 5 and 5s so I'm not sure that this would help.